# Select columns using LINQ but without a ModelView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if can I SELECT some columns without use any ModelView or Pre-defined object.

Something like this

```
    List<Iden_User> users = new List<Iden_User>();
    users = DB.Users.Select(r => new { r.UserName.... })
.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Today I'm doing it

```
List<Iden_User> users = new List<Iden_User>();
users = DB.Users.OrderBy(r => r.UserName).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
var userObject = users.Select(r => new { r.UserName,r.user_Status });
```

Thank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var userObject = DB.Users.OrderBy(r => r.UserName).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize)
                         .Select(r => new { r.UserName, r.user_Status })
                         .ToList();
```

You can't use "users" in your first code sample because that is of type Iden_User. Your query results is an anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks mate!

It was my mistake. 
I was trying to convert to the wrong object.

I tried the same code, but without the correct var, like

List<Iden_User> userObject = new List<Iden_User>() instead of Object usersObject = new Object()